# Opening Speech_Recognition python program with cronjob executes correctly but doesn't do anything?

Tags: python, cron, speech-recognition, pyaudio, raspberry-pi4

I've been trying to have a cronjob open a control python script that opens a speech_recognition program by means of subprocess.Popen(). However, whenever I reboot my Pi, the cronlog gives me the normal warnings and stuff that is perfectly fine:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.front.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=1'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=1,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 1}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

This log is normal and when I run this program (speech.py) in the terminal it gives me the same log but actually starts listening for my voice. But if I run this program via cronjob, it refuses to listen (since I have an indicator LED that should light up when voice script is activated but it doesn't). Despite the below log, which indicates nothing went wrong, it does not work.

Here is my control code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as IO
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call, Popen

#Popen(['npm', 'run', 'start'], shell=False)
Popen(['python3', 'speech.py'], shell=False)
sleep(8)

dashboard = True
voice = True



open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('true')
open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('true')

IO.setwarnings(False)
IO.setmode(IO.BCM)

voiceCtrl = 20
dashCtrl = 21
LED = 11

IO.setup(voiceCtrl, IO.IN, pull_up_down=IO.PUD_UP)
IO.setup(dashCtrl, IO.IN, pull_up_down=IO.PUD_UP)
IO.setup([LED, 12], IO.OUT)

#loop and check for input
try:
    while True:
        #if voice control button is pressed:
        if IO.input(voiceCtrl) == 0:
            if open('Voice.txt','r').read() == 'true':
                voice = True
            else:
                voice = False
            if not voice:
                voice = True
                open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('true')
                Popen(['python3', 'speech.py'], shell=False)
                sleep(3)
        #if dash control button is pressed:
        if IO.input(dashCtrl) == 0:
            if open('ToF.txt', 'r').read() == 'true':
                dashboard = True
            else:
                dashboard = False
            if not dashboard:
                dashboard = True
                Popen(['npm', 'run', 'start'], shell=False)
                #short display power button
                sleep(3.75)
                IO.output(12, True)
                sleep(0.5)
                IO.output(12, False)
                open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('true')
            else:
                dashboard = False
                #short display power button
                IO.output(12, True)
                sleep(0.5)
                IO.output(12, False)
                sleep(1.5)
                call(['sudo', 'killall', 'electron'], shell=False)
                open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('false')
        sleep(0.65)
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    IO.output(LED, False)
    open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('false')
    IO.cleanup()
    call(['sudo', 'killall', 'python3'], shell=False)
    call(['sudo', 'killall', 'electron'], shell=False)
    exit(1)

open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('false')
IO.output(LED, False)
IO.cleanup()
call(['sudo', 'killall', 'python3'], shell=False)
exit(0)
```

I know it's messy, I still have to clean that up. Same goes for the speech_recognition code (speech.py):

```
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call, Popen
import RPi.GPIO as IO
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

pyaudio.PyAudio().open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                       rate=44100,
                       channels=2,
                       input_device_index=11,
                       input=True,
                       output=False,
                       frames_per_buffer=1024)

LED = 11
lichten = False
dashboard = True
if open('ToF.txt', 'r').read() == 'true':
    dashboard = True
else:
    dashboard = False

IO.setmode(IO.BCM)
IO.setwarnings(False)

IO.setup(LED, IO.OUT)

IO.setup([10,12,14,15,17,18,22,27], IO.OUT)
IO.output([10,14,15,17,18,22,27], True)

r = sr.Recognizer()
list = sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
dev_index = list.index('default')

microphone = sr.Microphone(device_index=dev_index, chunk_size=256)
try:
    while True:
        with microphone as source:

            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            
            try:
                print("Zeg iets..")
                
                IO.output(LED, True)
                
                audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 4)
                text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = "nl-NL").lower()
                
                print(text)
                
                IO.output(LED, False)
                
                if "licht" in text and "schakel" in text:
                    if lichten:
                        IO.output([14,17], True)
                        lichten = False
                    else:
                        IO.output([14,17], False)
                        lichten = True
                
                if "lamp" in text and "uit" in text:
                    IO.output(27, False)
                elif "lamp" in text and "aan" in text:
                    IO.output(27, True)
                
                if "heater" in text and "uit" in text:
                    IO.output(18, True)
                elif "heater" in text and "aan" in text:
                    IO.output(18, False)                    
                    
                if "kanaal 2" in text and "uit" in text:
                    IO.output(15, False)
                elif "kanaal 2" in text and "aan" in text:
                    IO.output(15, True)
                    
                if "kanaal 3" in text and "uit" in text:
                    IO.output(22, False)
                elif "kanaal 3" in text and "aan" in text:
                    IO.output(22, True)
                    
                if "kanaal 4" in text and "uit" in text:
                    IO.output(10, False)
                elif "kanaal 4" in text and "aan" in text:
                    IO.output(10, True)
                if "dashboard" in text:
                    if open('ToF.txt', 'r').read() == 'true':
                        dashboard = True
                    else:
                        dashboard = False
                    if "uit" in text:
                        if dashboard:
                            dashboard = False
                            #short display power button
                            IO.output(12, True)
                            sleep(0.5)
                            IO.output(12, False)
                            call(['sudo', 'killall', 'electron'], shell=False)
                            open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('false')
                    elif "aan" in text:
                        if not dashboard:
                            dashboard = True
                            Popen(['npm', 'run', 'start'], shell=False)
                            #short display power button
                            sleep(3.75)
                            IO.output(12, True)
                            sleep(1)
                            IO.output(12, False)
                            open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('true')
                    
                if "ik ga slapen" in text:
                    IO.output([14,17,27], False)
                    if dashboard:
                        dashboard = False
                        #short display power button
                        IO.output(12, True)
                        sleep(0.5)
                        IO.output(12, False)
                        call(['sudo', 'killall', 'electron'], shell=False)
                        open('ToF.txt', 'w').write('false')
                    open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('false')
                    break
                
                if "voice" in text and "uit" in text:
                    break
                
                
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                IO.output(LED, False)
                print("Not understood")
            except sr.RequestError:
                print("Request Failed: Check de internet verbinding")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    IO.output(LED, False)
    open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('false')
    IO.output([10,14,15,17,22,27], True)
    IO.output(LED, False)
    IO.cleanup()

IO.output([10,14,15,17,22,27], True)
IO.output(LED, False)
open('Voice.txt', 'w').write('false')
IO.cleanup()
```

As you can see, I added some PyAudio configuration to make sure I didn't get an 'Unanticipated Host Error' or Invalid number of channels' error.

The weirdest thing is, is that it does work on a terminal or within the Thonny IDE but it just ignores my cronjob entirely on boot.

Comment: hi @DanieldH welcome to SO! Did you check the permissions on your `/dev` entries for your soundcard? It could be that your cronjob is running with permissions that don't have access to the sound card.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).